# ¿Cómo borrar un documento en Firebase (Cloud Firestore)?

Tags: angular, firebase, delete

Agradezo su respuesta de antemano.

Sucede que estoy intentando eliminar un documento de firebase (Cloud Firestore). Necesito el ID para eso. Pero el id no esta en el arreglo que recibo al ejecutar: return this.db.collection('enterprises').valueChanges();

El arreglo que entrega esa linea de código solo incluye las propiedades que yo escribí solamente (nombre, email)

Solo al ejecutar this.db.collection('enterprises').snapshotChanges(); recibo otro arreglo raro, de donde obtengo los id que hay en el documento (arreglo.payload.doc.id). y el arreglo de la data mediante: arreglo.payload.doc.data();

El problema es que el arreglo de Id lo obtengo aparte, y no dentro del arreglo anterior. Para solucionarlo hice una mezcla de los arreglos y así quedo el arreglo con el id dentro. Pero la pregunta es: Es esa la forma de hacerlo? O existe otra forma de eliminar el documento sin tener que hacer esa mezcla de arreglos? (Lo hice con un foreach)

Codigo:

component.ts

```
mixInfo() {
this.userService.mixInfo().subscribe(r => {
  r.forEach(user => {
    const id = user.payload.doc.id;
    const data = <UserInterface>user.payload.doc.data();
    const { name, email, password, role } = data;
    this.userService.editUser(id, { id, name, email, password, role })
    this.getUsers();
  });
});
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gracias por sus respuestas, Finalmente este post me ayudó: https://medium.com/angular-chile/angular-6-y-firestore-b7f270adcc96

Comment: Por favor, no publiques una respuesta diciendo "gracias". En su lugar, **[acepta la respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)** que consideres como la mejor solución a tu problema. - [Desde revisión](/review/low-quality-posts/226327)

Comment: Solo me guiaron, pero ninguna fue una solución

Answer (score 0):

Grabriel creo que estás haciendo lo correcto ya que [en la propia documentación de Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#get_all_documents_in_a_collection) se muestra un uso donde el `doc.id` y los datos del documento `doc.data()` se obtienen por separado.

En mi caso uso esta forma de componer el documento todo el rato: guardo el ID auto-generado (o generado por mí) dentro del mapa:

```
const rooms = [];

const snapshot = db
  .collection("rooms")
  .orderBy("createdAt", "desc")
  .get();

snapshot.forEach(doc => {
  let room = doc.data();
  room.id = doc.id;
  rooms.push(room);
});
```

Saludos.

Comment: Gracias por responder! Pero que es db? Porque yo tengo afs, que es de tipo AngularFirestore. Trate de usar tu ayuda pero al hacer const snaptshot = afs.collection('users').get(); y despues el snapshot.ferEach(doc => { doc.data() }, el doc.data() marca error porque no existe. Entonces no se estamos haciendo algo distinto...

Comment: `db` es una referencia a una colección de Firestore (`export const db = firebase.firestore()`). En el ejemplo uso el SDK de JavaScript pero estoy seguro de que con AngularFire puedes también crear una referencia a una colección de tu base de datos. A partir de ahí y siguiendo el ejemplo puedes recorrer el `snapshot` y añadiendo una propiedad más con la `id` del documento.